# How can I check if a user closed a specific tab/window in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am running a server that allows users to detect motion via their webcam. The motion detector window/URL streams a live feed and I want to detect when the stream/motion detection was cut off if the user closes the window/tab directly instead of clicking the stop button.

I tried searching for a solution online but could not find one.

Here's the code for the route in the flask app

```
@app.route('/camera')
@login_required
def camera():
    return Response(get_frame(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

The 'get_frame()' passed in the *Response* above does not have a *return* statement, it uses *yield* instead to provide the images from webcam as a motion picture.

```
def get_frame():
    ....
    ....
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
        b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n' + imageData + b'\r\n')
```

I want to detect it to create timestamps for when the motion detector was started and when it stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain and simple solution is to write a last sent batch timestamp to a request:

```
from flask import request

def get_frame():
    ....
    request.last_batch_send_time = time.time()
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
        b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n' + imageData + b'\r\n')
```

Then you can use it in an [after request callback](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/deferredcallbacks/), for example.

Comment: Thanks, it actually gave me a much better idea to implement this. I will keep you posted :)